# Shared Preferences Returning last value after restarting?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, dynamically-generated

I'm using shared preference to store dynamically created buttons and also using it to store the label of dynamically generated buttons after renaming them. Application works fine till generating buttons but the problem is with labeling. If Label three buttons as Test1, Test2, Test3 and so on. But after restarting application all the generated buttons have label Test3 on them.`Code in MainActivity`

```
 SharedPreferences prefs=null;
int count = 0;

"Code in onCreate method"

prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    count=prefs.getInt("count", 0);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
            final Button myButton = new Button(this);
            myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            reportDialog(myButton.getText().toString());
                        }
                });

            myButton.getId();
            myButton.setText(prefs.getString("key","New"));
            myButton.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
                public boolean onLongClick(View arg0)
                    {
                        AlertDialog lbldialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
                        lbldialog.setTitle("Change Button Label");
                        lbldialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);   
                        lbldialog.setMessage("Enter new Button label  to change");
                        final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);                 
                        lbldialog.setView(input);
                        lbldialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Change", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                                    {
                                        myButton.setText(input.getText());
                                        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                                        edit.putString("key", myButton.getText().toString());
                                        edit.commit();
                                    }
                            });

                        lbldialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", 
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Label not Changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                            });
                        lbldialog.show();   
                return true;  
                }
        });
        ll.addView(myButton, lp);
    }

"Code to add new buttons:"

if(v == btnaddnew)  

{    final Button btn1 = new Button(this);
btn1.setText("New");
btn1.setId(23);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        rptDialog(btn1.getText().toString());
        }
    })
btn1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
        //Dialog Box pops up with edit text field to change button label
        AlertDialog lbldialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        lbldialog.setTitle("Change Button Label");
        lbldialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);   
        lbldialog.setMessage("Enter new Button label  to change");
        final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        lbldialog.setView(input);
        lbldialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Change",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                    {
                        btn1.setText(input.getText());
                        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                        edit.putString("key", btn1.getText().toString());
                        edit.commit();

                    }
            });

        lbldialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Label not Changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        lbldialog.show();   
    return true; 
     }
    });         
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
    ll.addView(btn1, lp);
    count++;
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("count", count);
    editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: You are using the same string "key" to save the labels of all the buttons so it is overwritten. The last label which you have saved is retained in sharedpreferences.

Comment: @Andrew T. can you suggest edits for that

Comment: use "key"+n -for the nth button as a key to store the value

Comment: @user2450263 is there a need to declare "n" as integer, boolean etc

Comment: @user3172071 check the answer. Also, yes if you use the "n", will be an integer. But might as well use the "i" for the for loop

Answer (score 0):

You are using same key for all the buttons:

```
btn1.setText(input.getText());
Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putString("key", btn1.getText().toString());
edit.commit();
```

You should create different keys like key1, key2 and key3 for each of these.

Answer (score 0):

as its inside the for loop- (?)

```
edit.putString("key"+i, myButton.getText().toString());
```

the "i" will be from the for loop then

Answer (score 0):

```
Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putString("key1", myButton.getText().toString());
edit.commit();

Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putString("key2", btn1.getText().toString());
edit.commit();
```