# Dynamically created buttons have same label after restarting application?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, dynamically-generated

I'm using a `predefined button` to generate `new buttons` when click on it. After generating new buttons I wish to `change their label` for that I'm using `EditText` defined in dialog box which pops up `onLongClick` of new generated buttons. To store all the generated buttons and their label I'm using `Shared preferences`. But the problem is after restarting all the generated buttons have same label on them.

```
code in mainactivity-----
SharedPreferences prefs=null;
String key;
int btncount = 15;

code in onCreate method----
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
btncount=prefs.getInt("count", 0);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
for(int i=0;i<btncount;i++)
    {
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
        final Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.getId();
        myButton.setText(prefs.getString(key+myButton.getId(),"New"));
        myButton.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0)
                {
                    AlertDialog lbldialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
                    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);                 
                    lbldialog.setView(input);
                    lbldialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Change", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                                {
                                myButton.setText(input.getText());
                                    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                                    edit.putString(key+myButton.getId(), myButton.getText().toString());
                                    edit.commit();
                                }
                        });

                lbldialog.show();   
        return true;  
        }
});
ll.addView(myButton, lp);}

Code to create button-----
if(v == btnaddnew)                      
{
        final Button btn1 = new Button(this);
        btn1.setText("New");
        btn1.setId(btncount);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            reportDialog(btn1.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        btn1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                AlertDialog lbldialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                lbldialog.setView(input);
                lbldialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Change",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                        {
                            btn1.setText(input.getText());
                            Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                            edit.putString(key+btn1.getId(), btn1.getText().toString());
                            edit.commit();

                        }
                });

            lbldialog.show();   
        return true;  
            }
        });         
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
        ll.addView(btn1, lp);
        btncount++;
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("count", btncount);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Check it once and please provide me with proper edits as I'm new to android and I dont have that much knowledge

Comment: you always create your button with `new` label you must first check your `SP` and if is empty then create with `new` else you need set label to value that store in `SP`

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan first I'm creating new buttons with label "new" after that I'm changing their label to test1, test2, test3...... but after restarting all buttons have label as test3

Comment: Duplicate question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577082/buttons-generated-on-runtime-have-same-label-after-restarting-app] and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620270/shared-preferences-returning-last-value-after-restarting] also same

Comment: can you show us when you restore value from `SP`?

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan the shared preference file contain this entry :`<int value="5" name="count"/><string name="null4">labek</string><string name="null-1">label 34</string>`

Comment: why you `concat` id with `Key` that has no value and it's null? where you restore label in your activity? please show the code

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan this is my complete code regarding buttons

Answer (score 0):

i see one problem in your code,

you write bellow code:

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
final Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setText(prefs.getString(key+myButton.getId(),"New"));
```

you create one new button so this button don't have any id so how you want `getId()` from that? this line retrieve `nullnull`. because `getid()` is null and `key` is null too. you need change that code.

you try set Key of your button in SP with `key+btn1.getId()` that key is `null` , why you don't use `btn1.getId()` as key in `SP` ?

and for retrieving your label just use `i` in for statement.