# Error: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first and then application crashes?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I create this post, because i am new to android development, and i need a little help. I am doing a little exercise about a application from which you can `dynamically generate buttons` on click of `predefined button` and also `can send message to predefined number` . After generating first button when i again click to add more `Buttons` the error occurs "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first".

Code in onCreate method:

```
btnlabel = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
reltxt = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
loadSharedPreferences();
```

Code for shared preferences to save buttons

```
preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
btncount = preferences.getInt("count", 0);

for(int i=0;i<btncount;i++)
{

    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);


    final Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.getId();
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            addbtn(btn.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    btn.setText(preferences.getString("btn"+btn.getId(),"New"));
            AlertDialog btndelete = delete.create();
            btndelete.show(); 
            return true;  
            }
    });
ll.addView(btn, lp);    
}
```

Code for AlertDialog box to add buttons and send message

```
public void addbtn(final String title)
{
AlertDialog.Builder addreport = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
addreport.setTitle(title);
LinearLayout addlayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
addlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

buttonlabel.setTextKeepState(title);
addlayout.addView(buttonlabel);

TextView relatedtxt = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
relatedtxt.setText("Enter Text");
relatedtxt.setTextSize(18);
addlayout.addView(relatedtxt);  

reltxt.setTextKeepState("Hi.. How are you");
addlayout.addView(reltxt);  

addreport.setView(addlayout);
addreport.setNeutralButton("SUBMIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        String tempTxt = btnlabel.getText().toString();
        if(title.equals(tempTxt))
        {
            sendSms();
        }

        else
        {
            addnewDialog();
            sendSms();
        }

        dialog.dismiss();   
        }
    });
AlertDialog adrptdialog = addreport.create();
adrptdialog.show();}
```

Code to add Buttons

```
public void addnewDialog()
    {
for(int i=0; i<btncount; i++){
        final Button btn = new Button(MainActivity.this);
        btn.setText(btnlabel.getText());
btn.setId(i);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
        ll.addView(btn, lp);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                 addbtn(btn.getText().toString());
             }
        });
        btncount++;
        Editor edit = preferences.edit();
        edit.putString("btn"+btn.getId(), btn.getText().toString());
        edit.putInt("count", btncount);
        edit.commit();}
```

Can anyone check What's going on? and correct me where I'm wrong.

Comment: move `LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);` in `for` statement

Comment: You should find out l1 linear Layout in the loop.

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan still showing same error

Comment: you don't initialize `buttonlabel` on `addbtn`

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan I've initailize `buttonlabel` and `reltxt` in main activity so that it should be accessible to both `addbtn` method and `sendSms` method.

Comment: move those to both method

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan thanks man it works and also there is problem all dynamically generated buttons have same label after restart I mean to say if buttons stored with labels test1. test2, test3 after restart all buttons have label test3 on them

Comment: i answer this before for you on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719730/dynamically-created-buttons-have-same-label-after-restarting-application

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan can you provide me edits for the same if possible as  i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Main Answer**

answered on comment

**UPDATE 1**

as you say on comment all label is same each other, because you try following code:

```
edit.putString("btn"+btn.getId(), btn.getText().toString());
```

you don't set any id to your Button but you try `getId` from that. (`btn.getId()`)

when you use above code you have something like

```
edit.putString("btnnull", btn.getText().toString());
```

as you see all key of button is same each other and they override each other  in `SP` because we don't have duplicate `key` in `SP` then all label became last value that you entered.

**What You Have To Do**

you need set the id to your button like `btn.setId(i)`; that `i` is unique and incremental.

```
0 < i < btncount
```

**UPDATE 2**

you need `SeId` on `Code for shared preference` you try `getId` again from `new button`

**What You Have To Do**

just change follow line

```
final Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.getId();
```

to

```
final Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.SetId(i);
```

Comment: to btn in SP or where I'm creating new buttons and is there any edit to perform where i'm creating Buttons

Comment: where you creating new button, i don't get second part of your question

Comment: what I'm actually want to know is what edit I need to perform in SP and what edits i need to perform where I'm creating buttons. and thanks for your concern and help.

Comment: you need setId to your button while crating new button, just this, and while saving value on SP just `getId`, i right this on my answer

Comment: now its not creating buttons. check my edits for SP and add newbtn method for what I've done.

Comment: when I use loop to create buttons ` for(int i=1;i<btncount;i++){ final Button btn = new Button(this); btn.setId(i);} `and in SP `btn.getId();`
buttons are not created and there is no SP file.
and when no loop is used to create buttons `buttons will be created but with same error as mention in question`

Comment: SP means shared Preference, what is the new problem now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48232/discussion-between-shayan-pourvatan-and-android-beginner)

Comment: the problem is when create buttons without using `for(i=1;i<btncount;i++){ btn.setId(i)}` buttons will be created and when restart all buttons have same label but when using `for(i=1;i<btncount;i++) { button btn = new button(this); btn.setId(i);` and using btn.setId(i) in SP in both cases.